# How to implement Back button functionality in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

As we know In ionic 4 they replaced push and pop fucntionality with navigateForward and navigateBack. But by using this method i am not able to get back button in status bar. Any one is having any idea how to implement back button in ionic 4?

Comment: requirement is i need back button on top

Comment: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your HTML, go to `ion-toolbar` tag inside `ion-header` tag and add the back button as

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
   <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

This will add a back button at top left corner of your page and clicking on it will take you to previous route.

For more configs of back-button check the official Ionic v4.0 docs at https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button/

Comment: As it said in answers, don't forget `defaultHref="home"` attribute unless it won't show any button.

Answer (score 6):

could you please trying to add back button in ion-toolbar .

```
 <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref=""></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks like there may be an issue where you need to supply a `defaultHref` attribute to get this to show up.  On the surface this seems like annoying overhead, but I guess it does make you think about navigation paths for each page.  Not ideal, but not horrible.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-back-button-angular/137866/18

Comment: that works but what about if we are not moving between pages and we're just opening a modal (with same url we had before open it)

Comment: fixed using this https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/a03c311dfbf7fc58f6a9143859a6b5a33f1917d0/src/demos/api/modal/index.html#L38 but not exactly the same